# Why would you use imagecolorallocate if you can just use an int?

Tags: php, image, image-processing, colors, bit-shift

In PHP, what is the difference between using imagecolorallocate,

```
$color = imagecolorallocate($im, $red, $green, $blue);
```

and using a bitshift based int?

```
$color = ($red << 16) + ($green << 8) + ($blue);
```

Which of the two gives the best performance when looping through an image and calling **imagesetpixel($im, $x, $y, $color);**

I'm not taking alpha channels in consideration for this example, but that's also easier with bitshifting. In a lot of examples, you see people using imagesetpixel and then doing the alpha with a 24 bit bitshift.

What are the pros of using imagecolorallocate compared to bitshifting the whole int?

Comment: _"Which of the two gives the best performance"_ - Writing a test for that would probably have gone faster than posting this question.

Comment: Color allocation is required for [specific image types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indexed_color).

Comment: it's a palleted image helper function.

Comment: For true color images, there's no difference. `imagecolorallocate` ends up wrapping `gdTrueColorAlpha` in lib-gd, which is [literally just a bitshifting macro](https://github.com/libgd/libgd/blob/fdbd8df68222151b62571b0419ac1eb5683f73ba/src/gd.h#L942).

Comment: I decided to do a few performance tests and they seem to be quite equal in speed in this testcase (with true colors). If I take the average (of 10) of my testcases, the difference is about 1% in time, sometimes leaning towards imagecolorallocate, sometimes leaning towards bitshifting.